# Spanish Localization using kotlin language in Android

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, localization, internationalization

I am facing a strange issue in my project trying to localize my application to Spanish. I have followed the simple steps; Added Spanish locale from translator editor through layout option. And inserted all the Spanish strings in string.xml(es) file. Now, when I am changing it to Spanish language in device, all the strings are still in English.
This is strange as I made a sample application and followed the same steps and it is working fine for that sample.

P.S: I have followed MVVM design pattern where I am doing a dependency injection.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Neel

***More Details:***
This is a big project. So, what I did, I created a sample project and did the same steps to change the language. So, language changes and I am getting as Spanish language code 'es' when I run the below code:

```
Print("Location locale" + "  " + Locale.getDefault().language)
```

But when I run this code in my project; I am getting 'en' code although the device language is Spanish. I have searched all the code; I am not setting any 'en' value anywhere in the project. Is there any specific code which I should search for in order to make sure about it.

Please help!

Comment: Are you using Data binding?

Comment: if you restarted the application in between, e.g. due to reinstalling it, the only reasons why it wouldn't work should be either a) don't have the spanish strings in your app (build or install failed or you actually put them not in -es) or b) you're using the wrong strings in your app, e.g. hardcoded leftovers or ones with different id. If you didn't restart the app it might be a case of cached / leaked context not loading the right resources. You can also log what `Locale.getDefault()` gives you, should be something -es if it worked.

Comment: Hi @zapl, User would be able to change language from English to Spanish and vice-versa via menu button is my use case. But currently, I want to have the default behavior i.e it should change when we change the device locale. Now, I am having problem in the default behavior itself. I am following the simple steps; created Spanish localization file through editor and replaced some of the strings to Spanish. But unfortunately, having issues in the string conversion.

Comment: is `Locale.getDefault.language` still showing "en" after restart of the app (or even reboot of the device)?  In that case you may have done something wrong when changing the device language.  (E.g. changed the location only or just the timezone). For example the settings will be in spanish when you successfully changed the language

Comment: Hi Zapl, The language in the settings is Spanish. I just followed the steps mentioned on internet to change the language from settings by adding another language and marking it default. I print the log by the method : Timber.i(" Language Locale" + " " + Locale.getDefault().language) and it. is showing me - Language Locale en. It means it is not converted to Spanish for my application. Is there any other way to change language for my application from the phone settings.

Comment: Hi @Arnab, Yes I am using data binding.

Comment: @Neel string resource will not work normally if u use data binding.

Comment: Which language are you using for development Kotlin or Java?

Comment: Hi Arnab, I am using Kotlin language. Do I need to tweak something in order to make it work.

Comment: Yes, if you use databinding you cannot set text from xml for dynamic text of textView from kotlin class you have to do it. I had faced same problem and solved it as well. if you can post some lines of code I will be easy to explain solution for me.

Comment: There is no `Locale.setDefault` in your code, e.g. `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH)`? That's the only reason I can imagine why you don't get `es` via `getDefault`

Answer (score 0):

Place `strings.xml` with Spanish translations in `res/values-es` folder.

Comment: Hi Sergey, Thank you for your reply. The strings.xml is already there in res/values-es folder. I checked in the project drop down.

Comment: Try to clean your Project and Rebuild it. If it doesn't help try `File/Invalidate Caches` (it is menu item of Android Studio) and then click `Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: did this as well. I tried many alternative but it is not working. Do I need to replace all the strings in Spanish. I am trying with maximum Spanish words but not all because of its quantity.

Comment: Also, when I checked the language by using "Locale.getDefault.language"; it is showing "en" but my device language is "es". I don't know what to do.

Comment: No, you don't need to translate all strings. The strings that are not translated just will be displayed in English. Try to test on another device or Emulator, maybe the problem in device. Or maybe somewhere in the code you set English explicitly, for example: `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);` or something like that.

Comment: if you're using an emulator you should be able to change the locale from the settings app within the emulator itself

Comment: @Sergey No, I have commented all the explicit language code from the application. Also, I have checked in both Device and emulator; the behavior is random for both the cases. It happened for one screen when I added the related strings but when I tried for second screen; it is not converting it to Spanish.

Comment: @user2340612 I have tested in both Emulator and Device. I think it is because of dependency injection or something because this is the only thing which I am doing different from my sample code.